# run the spring project from command line

Tags: spring, command-line

I have created one spring project in STS (spring source tool) which works (compile and execution) fine in STS, but when I am run the class file from terminal I am getting an error like this:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/XXXX/XXXX/Operations
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.XXXX.XXXX.Operations

For reference below is my .classpath file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
<classpathentry kind="src" output="target/classes" path="src/main/java" />
<classpathentry kind="src" output="target/test-classes"path="src/test/java" />
<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/
org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/J2SE-1.5" />
<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.m2e.MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER" />
<classpathentry kind="output" path="target/classes" />
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="var" path="M2_REPO" />
</classpath>
```

Comment: How are you running it from the terminal? What command are you using?

Comment: after reached in my target/classes folder using java com.XXXX.XXXX.Operations

Answer (score 1):

Your error suggests that the "Operations.class" file is not in the target/classes folder (or you have a typo in your package name).

First ensure your class is where you expect it:

```
cd [project root]/target/classes
ls com/XXXX/XXXX/Operations.class
```

If this proves the file is present, you should be able to use the java command you mentioned:

```
java com.XXXX.XXXX.Operations
```

Make sure you do not add ".class" at the end, as Java will assume you are trying to load a file called "class" in the "Operations" package.

If the file is missing (I expect it will be), you will need to execute a build in STS (`Project` -> `Build Project`) to create it.

---

### Update

You mention in the comments that you are getting the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/context/ApplicationContext
```

This is a very different problem, it means you have not referenced the Spring libraries in your java command, so Java doesn't know where to find them.

I recommend you package the program with STS before attempting to run it. This is the typical way Java developers build and deploy applications. [This article](http://www.online-etraining.com/creating-a-java-application) provides a simple tutorial on how to do this (STS is a variant of Eclipse).

Addition - your updated question suggests you are also using Maven in this application, in which case you can use "mvn package" to build the project instead of Eclipse. Read this tutorial to get started on using Maven: http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html

If you REALLY want to run the program without packaging it; you will need to reference **ALL** the Jar files you are using in the command (this is only an example, replace "spring.jar" with the correct Jar files you are using):

```
java -classpath .;../../lib/spring.jar com.XXXX.XXXX.Operations
```

Comment: I already checked, everything is present there even the program running from STS (ctrl+f11) but i am getting the error through command prompt (Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/context/ApplicationContext), even i tried java -classpath /home/test/.m2/repository/ com.XXXX.XXXX.Operations , java -classpath /home/test/.m2/repository/* com.XXXX.XXXX.Operations

Comment: Wait! That's a different error! Your question states "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.XXXX.XXXX.Operations", not "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/context/ApplicationContext"... I'll update my answer since this is a completely different problem.

Comment: as per guidelines export the project as a jar and these commands tried java -jar app.jar com.s.ss.App, java -classpath app.jar com.s.ss.App and getting same errorException in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/context/ApplicationContext

Comment: I have installed and create the jar from maven itself (without errro), it is reflected in my target/ (application-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar) but after execution (java -cp target/my-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar com.mycompany.app.App )getting the same error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/context /ApplicationContext Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext

Comment: finally it's work (not from the jar from class file) after adding the maven exec plugin and using this command mvn -X exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.XXXX.XXXX.Operations" thanks guys for ur help :)

Comment: @seanhodges : hi, thanks for answer as I am having same problem. But I am trying to execute and I am getting exception : org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException for my xml configuration file. Can you help?

Comment: @unknown it sounds like you have an XML syntax error in your spring config file. Post a separate question and include your application context XML

Answer (score 0):

Usually, people creates jar-file, which contains all classes and resources need to start the application. After that, its easy to start the app:

```
java -cp youapp-full.jar  com.XXXX.XXXX.Operations
```

And `Operations` class must have main method ofcourse

Comment: where i need to use these command inside the target/classes dir or where i kept my jar file

Comment: @seanhodges pointed right example how to create you app jar-file

Comment: now open jar-file(just rename it to *.zip) and search for your class in it.

Comment: I m in linux without rename itself I am able to see it, it contain all .class and .java file