# How to set Spring Classpath

Tags: java, spring, annotations, intellij-idea

[image: Error i n sfs console]

I am using IntelliJ and jus checked out working code from the svn.I am struggling to run the jar.

Its a simple core java Spring project.

Since I get the above error.I understand that the spring path is not set fine.
How do I handle it.?

```
 private ApplicationContext appContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(ApplicationRepositoryConfiguration.class);
```

Application context file is a bean class here (@Bean annotation is used). I am not using a xml file.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you are running your project from command line. Run following command :

> java -classpath spring.jar;spring-sec.jar,......so on com.example.UrMainClass

while specifying jar in command, make sure you provide complete path of jar. Also check this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/10122038/1065180

Comment: I am not running in command line . I deploy my jar in the SmartFox server. The screen shot is the logs in console

Comment: spring lib is not in classpath. Check it. Because java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/context/annotation/AnnotationConfigApplicationContext. which version of spring are you using?

Comment: @Nandakumar Sry for late reply. I use Spring 3.1.1

Comment: @Meenakshi : you didn't add spring libraries in classpath, add those in classpath, I am Nandkumar, please don't say Nandakumar, you know difference :D

Comment: Sry for the wrong name . I have imported all the required jars also . is there any other way I can confirm if the classpath is set well.