# Runnig spring via Daemon as Standalone

Tags: java, spring, daemon

I am trying to run Spring via Daemon service as stand alone application ofcourse.

I have configured run.sh script and added to it all Spring jars framework.

Now i am trying to execute my starting point class from the Daemon classes this way:

Code:
public class FeedDaemon implements Daemon
{
    public FeedDaemon()
    {
    }

```
protected final static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FeedDaemon.class);
protected boolean shouldBeRunning = false;
protected ProviderFactory runner = null;

@Override
public void destroy()
{
    runner = null;
}

@Override
public void init(DaemonContext arg0) throws Exception
{
    runner = new ProviderFactory();
}

public void start() throws RuntimeError, ConfigError
{
    log.info("Starting daemon");
    runner.start();
}

public void stop() throws Exception
{
    log.info("Starting Shutting daemon ...");
    runner.stop();
}
```

}

Code:

```
package com.spring.test;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

import com.spring.aspect.Spring3HelloWorld;
import com.spring.beans.ParkingCar.CarBean;
import com.spring.beans.ParkingCar.CarMaker;
import com.spring.beans.ParkingCar.FourWheelsVechile;
import com.spring.beans.ParkingCar.TwoWheelsVechile;
import com.spring.beans.ParkingCar.Vechile;
import com.spring.beans.ParkingCar.VechileDetails;
import com.spring.beans.calculator.CalculateNumbersHolderBean;
import com.spring.beans.calculator.CalculateStrategyBean;
import com.spring.beans.calculator.CalculatorBean;

public class Spring3HelloWorldTest
{

    static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Spring3HelloWorldTest.class);

    public static void execute()
    {
        try
        {   
            ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
            logger.debug("3");


            Vechile fourWheelsVechile = (FourWheelsVechile) context.getBean("Ambulance");
            fourWheelsVechile.drive();
            CarMaker carMaker = (CarMaker) context.getBean("carMaker");
            CarBean carBean = carMaker.createNewCar();
            carBean.driveCar();
        }
        catch (Throwable e)
        {
            logger.error(e);
        }

    }
}
```

And I get this error:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.commons.daemon.support.DaemonLoader.load(DaemonLoader.java:164)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/context/ApplicationContext
    at com.spring.runner.FeedDaemon.init(FeedDaemon.java:37)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320)
    ... 6 more
Cannot load daemon
Service exit with a return value of 3
```

thats my run.sh script:

export JAVA_HOME=/../
FIXGW=/../FIXGW
CLASSPATH=$FIXGW/lib/FeedHandler.jar:$FIXGW/lib/FixSpring.jar:$FIXGW/lib/org.springframework.web-sources-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:$FIXGW/lib/org.springframework.web.struts-sources-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:$FIXGW/lib/org.springframework.web.servlet-sources-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:$FIXGW/lib/org.springframework.web.portlet-sources-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:$FIXGW/lib/org.springframework.test-sources-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:$FIXGW/lib/org.springframework.orm-sources-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:$FIXGW/lib/org.springframework.jms-sources-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:$FIXGW/lib/org.springframework.jdbc-sources-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:$FIXGW/lib/org.springframework.context.support-sources-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:$FIXGW/lib/org.springframework.aspects-sources-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:$FIXGW/lib/org.springframework.transaction-sources-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:$FIXGW/lib/org.springframework.oxm-sources-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:$FIXGW/lib/org.springframework.instrument-sources-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:$FIXGW/lib/org.springframework.instrument.tomcat-sources-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:$FIXGW/lib/org.springframework.expression-sources-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:$FIXGW/lib/org.springframework.core-sources-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:$FIXGW/lib/org.springframework.context-sources-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:$FIXGW/lib/org.springframework.beans-sources-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:$FIXGW/lib/org.springframework.asm-sources-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:$FIXGW/lib/org.springframework.aop-sources-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:$FIXGW/lib/commons-daemon-1.0.3.jar

cd $FIXGW
/../jsvc -user fox \
-XX:+DisableExplicitGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:SurvivorRatio=16 \
-Dlog4j.configuration=file:$FIXGW/conf/log4j.properties \
-outfile /dev/null \
-errfile $FIXGW/logs/error.log \
-verbose -classpath $CLASSPATH \
com.spring.runner.FeedDaemon

Any idea?

thanks,
ray.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

spring jars are not in classpath. Check this my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11029504/how-to-set-spring-classpath/11029597#11029597). Add all libraries in classpath via command line(ofcourse in your shell script).

Well I see your problem now. You have source files in classpath. Those are mentioned as `org.springframework.web.servlet-sources-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar` while compiled jars are mentioned as `org.springframework.web.servlet-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar`

Comment: But the jars are in the classpath.. check my run.sh script

Comment: did you download complete zip file from spring source.org

Comment: yes I did and after I fixed it I get: 2012-07-01 13:22:36,091 com.spring.test.Spring3HelloWorldTest [ERROR] org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundErrororg/aopalliance/intercept/MethodInterceptor

Comment: @rayman : org.springframework.aop jar is not in classpath. check it.

Comment: Yes now I got other erros: 2012-07-01 14:00:40,146 com.spring.test.Spring3HelloWorldTest [ERROR] org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'Spring3HelloWorldBean' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Cannot proxy target class because CGLIB2 is not available. Add CGLIB to the class path or specify proxy interfaces. after I fixed that i got asm missing error. why isnt all bundled?

Comment: I had to add asm.jar, cglib-2.2.jar and aopalliacne-1.0.jar in order to make everything worked..

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have added all the jars containing the Spring java source (uncompiled code). You should instead add the jars not named ...-sources... to the class path.

Comment: How should it be named fully? please write me one jar example. thanks

Comment: If you used Maven the files you want should be right next to the source files. If not, the you want the files named spring-core-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar and so on.

Comment: Would it be better to use Maven on ANT? coz I know how to use ANT neve r used Maven before.

Comment: Think you are close to starting a very heated debate here ;-) Maven does have built in dependency handling with automatic downloads from different repositories. Practical and makes dependencies look easy but can in my opinion lead to a sense of false security thinking that dependency handling is easy. Instead of starting a long discussion here, search for Maven and you will find a lot of information what it is and descriptions of pros and cons.

Comment: Okie. so tell me how will you keep Spring running in the standalone application? I mean there must be some while method

Comment: Not knowing the rest of your application it's a bit hard to say, but you probably have code initializing the spring context. That code or at least one other non daemon thread (possibly started by the spring configuration) must keep running / wait until an exit condition is met. (Not clear to me how the Ambulance is related to the FeedDaemon)